# Архитектура Stack Overflow версия 2016

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow

> Данная публикация является [первой в серии](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/03/stack-overflow-a-technical-deconstruction/), посвященной архитектуре Stack Overflow. Рады приветствовать.

Чтобы получить представление о том, как все работает, начну со среднестатистических данных Stack Overflow за день. Для того чтобы вы могли сравнить текущие данные [с предыдущими, — по состоянию на ноябрь 2013 года](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/), — привожу показатели за 9.02.2016 и их отличие от статистики на 12.11.2013.

- **209 420 973** (+61 336 090) HTTP-запросов к балансировщику нагрузки.
- **66 294 789** (+30 199 477) из них приходится на загрузку страниц.
- **1 240 266 346 053** (+406 273 363 426) байт (1.24 TB) исходящего HTTP-трафика
- **569 449 470 023** (+282 874 825 991) байт (569 GB) совокупный входящий трафик.
- **3 084 303 599 266** (+1 958 311 041 954) байт (3.08 TB) совокупный исходящий трафик.
- **504 816 843** (+170 244 740) SQL-запросов (только от HTTP-запросов).
- **5 831 683 114** (+5 418 818 063) хитов Redis.
- **17 158 874** (за 2013 г. данные отсутствуют) поисковых запросов Elasticsearch.
- **3 661 134** (+57 716) запросов по меткам.
- **607 073 066** (+48 848 481) мс (168 часов) потрачено на выполнение SQL-запросов.
- **10 396 073** (-88 950 843) мс (2.8 часов) потрачено на хиты Redis.
- **147 018 571** (+14 634 512) мс (40.8 часов) потрачено на запросы генератора меток.
- **1 609 944 301** (-1 118 232 744) мс (447 часов) потрачено на обработку ASP.NET.
- **22.71** (-5.29) мс — среднее значение обработки страницы (19.12 мс для ASP.NET) для 49 180 275 страниц, сгенерированных по запросам.
- **11.80** (-53.2) мс в среднем (8.81 мс в ASP.NET) для 6 370 076 сгенерированных домашних страниц.

Вас может удивить резкое падение времени обработки для ASP.NET по сравнению с 2013 годом (на тот момент оно составляло 757 часов) на фоне увеличения количества запросов на 61 млн. в день. Этому есть две причины: [обновление аппаратного обеспечения в начале 2015 года](http://blog.serverfault.com/2015/03/05/how-we-upgrade-a-live-data-center/), и серьезная работа по настройке производительности самих приложений. Не стоит забывать: [производительность важна](http://blog.codinghorror.com/performance-is-a-feature/). Если вы хотите узнать об аппаратном обеспечении больше — не беспокойтесь, в следующей публикации мы предоставим детальную спецификацию аппаратного обеспечения для всех серверов, используемых сайтами (ссылку на материалы я предоставлю, как только они будут опубликованы).

Итак, что изменилось за последние два года? Кроме замены некоторых серверов и сетевого оборудования, не так уж и много. Вот список аппаратного обеспечения, на котором работают сайты в настоящий момент (с указанием отличий от 2013 г.):

- 4 Microsoft SQL сервера (2 из них — на новом железе).
- 11 IIS веб–сервера (новое железо).
- 2 сервера Redis  (новое железо).
- 3 сервера меток (2 из 3 — на новом железе).
- 3 сервера Elasticsearch (аналогично)
- 4 балансировщика нагрузки [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) (два были добавлены для поддержки CloudFlare).
- 2 сети (каждая на Nexus 5596 Core + 2232TM Fabric Extenders, с увеличенной пропускной способностью до 10Gbps).
- 2 межсетевых экрана Fortinet 800C (замена Cisco 5525-X ASA).
- 2 маршрутизатора Cisco ASR-1001 (замена маршрутизаторам Cisco 3945).
- 2 маршрутизатора Cisco ASR-1001-x (новые!).

Что же нам ***нужно*** для работы Stack Overflow? [По сравнению с 2013-м годом изменилось немногое](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/#core-hardware), но в связи с оптимизацией и упомянутым обновлением аппаратного обеспечения, все, что нам ***нужно*** — один-единственный веб-сервер. Благодаря случаю, мы уже несколько раз успешно это проверили. Уточню: я лишь говорю, что это работает, я не утверждаю, что работа на одном сервере — удачное решение, но каждый раз этот факт меня поражает.

Теперь, когда у нас есть исходные данные, которые позволяют понять общие масштабы, посмотрим, как мы генерируем наши замечательные веб-страницы. Поскольку не многие системы могут существовать обособленно (и наша — не исключение), архитектурные решения часто теряют смысл без ясного понимания того, каким образом компоненты системы должны взаимодействовать в контексте единого целого. Цель публикации — дать полную картину, полное представление о системе. Частные вопросы её работы будут подробнейшим образом рассмотрены во многих [последующих публикациях](https://trello.com/b/0zgQjktX/blog-post-queue-for-stack-overflow-topics). Данная публикация представляет собой общий обзор аппаратного обеспечения, а уже в следующей, я остановлюсь на спецификациях устройств более детально.

Для тех из вас, кто хотел бы узнать, как выглядит современное «железо», я сделал несколько снимков стойки А (у которой есть сестра-близнец, стойка В) во время нашего [февральского обновления 2015-го года](http://blog.serverfault.com/2015/03/05/how-we-upgrade-a-live-data-center/):

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

… а для фанатов — [полный альбом тех дней, состоящий из 256 фотографий](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwK6E.jpg) (да, вы правы, такое количество фотоснимков отнюдь не случайно). Теперь углубимся в конфигурацию. Ниже логический обзор основных используемых систем:

[img3 http://nickcraver.com/blog/content/SO-Architecture-Overview-Logical.svg](http://nickcraver.com/blog/content/SO-Architecture-Overview-Logical.svg)

#### Основополагающие правила

Несколько правил, которые действуют всегда, и мы не будем повторять их перед каждым разделом:
- У всего есть копия.
- Все сервера и сетевое оборудование соединены как минимум 2 x 10Gbps.
- Все сервера имеют по 2 независимых входа питания от 2 источников бесперебойного питания с 2 резервными генераторами и 2 вспомогательными входами питания.
- Все сервера имеют резервную связь между стойками A и B.
- Все сервера и сервисы продублированы в дата-центре в Колорадо (все остальное оборудование находится преимущественно в Нью-Йорке).
- У всего есть копия.

#### Сеть Интернет

Сначала нас надо найти — а это DNS. И найти нас надо быстро, поэтому мы делегируем эту задачу (в данный момент) [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), поскольку их DNS-сервера расположены максимально близко к любому компьютеру в любой точке земного шара. Мы обновляем наши DNS-записи через API, которые выполняют задачу хостинга DNS. Поскольку мы настоящие параноики в том, что касается надежности соединения, мы, в дополнение, позаботились и о собственных DNS-серверах. И если в случае Апокалипсиса (причиной которого, вероятно, станет GPL, [Punyon](https://twitter.com/JasonPunyon) или кэширование) люди, чтобы отвлечься, все еще захотят программировать, мы будем в состоянии предоставить им качественную связь.

После того, как вы обнаруживаете наше тайное убежище, HTTP-трафик поступает от одного из четырех наших ISP (Level 3, Zayo, Cogent, и Lightower в Нью-Йорке) и направляется одним из наших четырех граничных маршрутизаторов. Мы взаимодействуем с ISP при помощи протокола [BGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) (довольно стандартного), контролируя поток трафика и обеспечивая несколько путей наиболее эффективного его приема. Маршрутизаторы [ASR-1001](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/asr-1001-router/index.html) и [ASR-1001-X](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/asr-1001-x-router/index.html) работают попарно, при этом каждая пара обслуживает по 2 ISP в режиме «активный-активный» — резервное копирование обеспечено. Несмотря на то, что все они находятся в одной и той же физической сети пропускной способностью 10Gbps, внешний трафик идет через выделенные изолированные [VLAN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLAN), к которым также подключены балансировщики нагрузки. Итак, после маршрутизаторов, трафик попадает на балансировщик нагрузки.

Думаю, сейчас самое время упомянуть, что между двумя нашими дата-центрами запущен сервис 10Gbps [MPLS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPLS), однако, не задействованный непосредственно в обслуживании сайтов. Этот сервис мы используем для репликации данных и быстрого восстановления при возрастании нагрузки. «Но, Ник, где же здесь резервирование?» Что ж, теоретически вы правы ([в лучшем смысле этого слова](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo)), тут мы ошиблись — на первый взгляд. Но подождите! У нас есть еще два отказоустойчивых маршрутизатора [OSPF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSPF) (MPLS идет под номером 1, два сервера OCPF — под номерами 2 и 3, в порядке убывания себестоимости), работающие у наших ISP. Каждая из упомянутых групп подсоединяется к соответствующей группе в Колорадо, и они делят между собой нагрузку в случае отказа. Мы могли бы связать обе группы с одной стороны и обеими группами с другой стороны, получив, таким образом, 4 пути, но… Неважно. Идем дальше.

#### Балансировщики нагрузки ([HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/))

Балансировщики нагрузки используют [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) 1.5.15 на [CentOS 7](https://www.centos.org/), нашей любимой версии Linux. Трафик TLS (SSL) также распределяется на HAProxy. Тем временем мы присматриваемся к HAProxy 1.7, который поддерживает [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2).

В отличие от остальных серверов с дублированием сетевого подключения 10Gbps LACP, каждый балансировщик нагрузки имеет по 2 пары, пропускной способностью 10Gbps: одна для внешней сети и одна для DMZ. Для повышения эффективности SSL-взаимодействия в этих боксах использовано 64GB и более памяти. Поскольку мы можем кэшировать для повторного использования больше сессий TLS, сокращаются работа по вычислениям при повторных подключениях к клиенту. Это означает, что мы сможем восстанавливать сессии и быстрее, и дешевле. Учитывая довольно низкую стоимость RAM в рублевом эквиваленте, выбор был прост.

Сами по себе балансировщики нагрузки устанавливаются достаточно легко. Мы прослушиваем различные сайты на разных IP (в основном, в целях ознакомления с сертификатами и управления DNS) и направляем трафик на различные терминалы в зависимости от названия сетевых узлов (в основном). Единственный примечательный факт в этом — ограничение скорости и сохранение данных о названиях узлов (отправляемых с нашего web-уровня) в [syslog-сообщении HAProxy](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#3.1-log), что позволяет нам записывать метрики производительности для каждого запроса. [Позже мы на этом также остановимся](https://trello.com/c/1Oc9cC6u/11-monitoring).

#### Веб-уровень (IIS 8.5, ASP.Net MVC 5.2.3 и .Net 4.6.1)

Балансировщики нагрузки передают трафик на 9 серверов, которые мы называем основными (01-09) и на два «dev/meta»-сервера (10-11, наша вспомогательная среда). Основные сервера обеспечивают работу Stack Overflow, Careers и всех сайтов Stack Exchange, кроме meta.stackoverflow.com и meta.stackexchange.com, которые работают на последних двух серверах. Основное приложение, сервис вопросов и ответов – распределенное. Это означает, что одно приложение отвечает на запросы всех сайтов вопросов и ответов. Иными словами, вся сеть сайтов вопросов и ответов может функционировать на одном пуле приложения, находящемся на одном сервере. Остальные приложения, такие как Careers, API v2, Mobile API и т.п. обособлены. Вот как выглядит первичный уровень и dev-уровень в IIS:

[image: img4]

[image: img5]

Так выглядит распределение Stack Overflow по веб-уровню в [Opserver](https://github.com/Opserver/Opserver) (наша внутренняя панель мониторинга):

[image: img6]

… а так выглядят сервера с точки зрения загрузки:

[image: img7]

В следующих публикациях я подробнее остановлюсь на причинах подобной избыточности, а пока назову основное: загрузка программных версий, резерв мощности, резервное копирование.

#### Сервисный уровень (IIS, ASP.Net MVC 5.2.3, .Net 4.6.1 и HTTP.SYS)

За веб-серверами стоит очень похожий сервисный уровень. Он также использует IIS 8.5 на Windows 2012R2. Этот уровень задействует внутренние сервисы для обеспечения работы продуктового веб-уровня и других внутренних систем. Два основных игрока здесь — Stack Server, использующий сервер меток и http.sys (без привязки к IIS) и Providence API (на IIS). Забавный факт: я должен был установить соответствие, определяющее, что каждый из этих двух процессов должен обрабатываться отдельным процессором, потому что при обновлении списков вопросов Stack Server занимает всю кэш-память L2 и L3 примерно на 2 минуты.

Эти сервисные элементы проделывают немалую работу для сервера меток и серверных API, для которых необходимо лишь резервное копирование (но отнюдь не девятикратное). Например, загрузка всех сообщений и их меток, которые меняются каждые n минут в соответствии с обновлениями в базе данных (а теперь их две) — задача не такая уж и простая. Мы не хотим обрушивать на веб-уровень такой объем, да еще и увеличенный в 9 раз — троекратного запаса для безопасной работы достаточно. Также мы по-разному настраиваем эти сервисные элементы на стороне аппаратного обеспечения — для лучшей оптимизации к различным характеристикам вычислительной нагрузки по индексации для сервера меток и elastic–индексации (которая также осуществляется здесь). Вообще, сервер меток — тема довольно сложная сама по себе, и ей будет посвящена [отдельная публикация](https://trello.com/c/DqklJDSF/29-tag-engine). Вкратце: когда вы открываете `/questions/tagged/java`, вы используете сервер меток, чтобы найти соответствующий вопрос. Он осуществляет *весь* поиск по меткам вне `/search`, поэтому [новая навигация](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) и пр. используют именно этот сервис для получения данных.

#### Буферная память и Pub/Sub ([Redis](http://redis.io/))

Мы используем [Redis](http://redis.io/) для выполнения нескольких функций: он надежен, как скала. Несмотря на внушительные 160 миллиардов операций в месяц, каждый экземпляр использует менее 2% CPU. Но обычно гораздо меньше:

[image: img8]

В случае с Redis, мы имеем кэш-систему L1/L2. «L1» — это HTTP Cache на веб-серверах или на любом задействованном приложении. «L2» обращается к Redis и выбирает элемент данных. Наши данные хранятся в формате [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) — благодарим [@Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) за его [protobuf-dot-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net). Для клиента мы используем [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) — написаного нами, общедоступного и бесплатного. Когда один веб–сервер получает непопадание сразу в кэш на L1 и на L2, он выбирает один элемент из источника данных (запрос базы данных, API-вызов и т.п.) и сохраняет результат — как в локальный кэш, так и в Redis. Следующий сервер, обращающийся к этому элементу, может получить непопадание на L1, но не на L2/Redis, что позволяет сохранить запрос к базе данных или API-вызов.

Мы обеспечиваем работу множества сайтов вопросов и ответов, и каждый сайт имеет собственное L1/L2-кэширование: по префиксу ключа на L1 и по идентификатору базы данных на L2/Redis. Более подробно об этом читайте [в нашей будущей публикации](https://trello.com/c/OztwfkG7/16-caching-Redis).

Наряду с двумя основными серверами Redis (первичным/вторичным), на которых работают все копии сайтов, у нас также есть самообучающаяся платформа, расположенная еще на двух подчиненных серверах (в связи с требованиями к объемам памяти), которая используется для реализации механизма рекомендации вопросов, отображаемых на домашней странице, улучшения алгоритма поиска вакансий и т. п.. Платформа называется «Providence», описание которой вы можете найти у [@Kevin Montrose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80572/kevin-montrose).

Основные сервера Redis имеют 256GB оперативной памяти (используется около 90GB), а сервера Providence — 384GB оперативной памяти (используется около 125GB).

Выбор Redis объясняется не только кэшированием, но также механизмом публикации и подписки – когда один сервер публикует сообщение, а все остальные подписчики его получают — включая нисходящих клиентов на вторичных серверах Redis. Мы используем этот механизм для очистки буферной памяти L1 на других серверах в случаях, когда для согласованности данных очистка производится только одним веб–сервером, но есть еще одна великолепная причина, по которой мы выбрали Redis – протокол Websockets.

#### Websockets ([NetGain](https://github.com/StackExchange/NetGain))

Мы используем Websockets для осуществления принудительных обновлений в режиме реального времени, таких как показ уведомлений в верхнем горизонтальном меню, подсчет голосов, формирование статистики [новой навигации](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate), показ новых ответов и комментариев, и еще для нескольких задач.

Сами сервера сокетов используют сырые сокеты, работающие на веб–уровне. Это очень тонкое приложение, использующее нашу открытую библиотеку: [StackExchange.NetGain](https://github.com/StackExchange/NetGain). При пиковой нагрузке мы поддерживаем около 500,000 открытых соединений Websocket **одновременно**, а это, на самом деле, довольно большое число браузеров. Забавный факт: некоторые из этих браузеров остаются открытыми в течение полутора лет и более, почему — неизвестно. Надо, чтобы кто-то проверил, живы ли люди по ту сторону экрана… Так выглядит график работы Websocket за эту неделю:

[image: img9]

Почему мы выбрали Websockets? Они в сотни раз эффективнее ждущего режима — если говорить о наших масштабах. Таким образом, мы можем предоставлять пользователю больше данных с большей скоростью, используя при этом меньше ресурсов. Однако не обошлось и без нюансов: динамический порт и недостаточность дескриптора файлов на балансировщике — курьезы, на которых мы [остановимся более подробно чуть позже](https://trello.com/c/7nv66g78/58-websockets).

#### Поиск ([Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch))

Спойлер: по этому поводу похвастаться нечем. Поиск на веб-уровне довольно прост и незамысловат — по сравнению с [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) 1.4, использующем очень тонкий высокопроизводительный клиент StackExchange.Elastic. Вразрез с нашей обычной политикой, планов открыть исходный код у нас нет — просто потому, что библиотека используемых нами API очень скромна. Я твердо уверен, что ее публикация вызвала бы непонимание разработчиков и принесла бы скорее вред, чем пользу. Мы используем Elasticsearch для `/search`, определения взаимосвязанных вопросов и генерации подсказок, которые выдаются в процессе создания вопросов.

Каждый кластер Elasticsearch (по одному в каждом из дата-центров) имеет 3 узла, и каждый сайт имеет свой собственный индекс (кроме Careers, который имеет несколько дополнительных индексов). Что делает нашу установку немного нетривиальной в терминах «эластичности»: наши 3 серверных кластера чуть мощнее среднего за счет SSD-хранилища, 192GB оперативной памяти и дублированной сети пропускной способностью 10Gbps для каждого из кластеров.

Домены приложений (да, с .NET CORE мы сплоховали…) на Stack Server, на которых находится механизм меток, также непрерывно индексируют элементы Elasticsearch. Здесь мы прибегли к простым уловкам: например, `ROWVERSION` в [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) (источник данных) сравнивается с документом «последней позиции» в Elastic. Поскольку он ведет себя как последовательность, мы можем просто проиндексировать любые элементы, изменившиеся с последнего прохода.

Главная причина, по которой мы выбрали Elasticsearch, а не что-то типа полнотекстового поиска SQL — его расширяемость и то, что он является более удачным выбором с точки зрения цена–производительность. Центральные процессоры SQL относительно дороги, а Elastic дешев, и, в данный момент, обладает большим набором функций. Почему не [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)? Нам нужен поиск по всей сети (одновременно по нескольким индексам), а на момент принятия решения эта возможность была недоступна. Почему мы еще не на 2.x — [значительное изменение в «типах»](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8870), которое для обновления требует полной переиндексации. И у меня пока просто нет времени внести необходимые изменения и составить план миграции.

#### Базы данных (SQL Server)

SQL-сервер является нашим единственным [источником информации](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth), все данные в Elastic и Redis поступают именно оттуда. У нас работают 2 кластера SQL-сервера с [AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510230.aspx). Каждый кластер имеет один первичный сервер (принимающий на себя почти всю нагрузку) и одну копию в Нью-Йорке. Дополнительно имеется еще одна копия в Колорадо (в нашем дата-центре аварийного восстановления). Все копии работают асинхронно.

Первый кластер представляет собой несколько серверов Dell R720xd, каждый на 384GB RAM, 4TB PCIe SSD и 2x 12 ядер. На нем работают Stack Overflow, Sites (плохое название; позже объясню), PRIZM и мобильные базы данных.

Второй кластер представляет собой несколько серверов Dell R730xd, каждый на 768GB RAM, 6TB PCIe SSD и 2x 8 ядер. На этом кластере работает *все остальное*. Список включает: [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), [Open ID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/), [систему чатов](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), [наш Журнал исключений](https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional) и все остальные сайты вопросов и ответов (напр., [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) и т.п.).

Мы хотим сократить до минимума использования CPU на уровне баз данных, но пока это невозможно в связи с некоторыми нюансами планирования кэша, которые в данный момент мы пытаемся исправить.

На текущий момент, NY-SQL02 и 04 являются первичными, 01 и 03 — копиями, которые мы перезапустили как раз сегодня во время обновлений SSD. Так выглядит статистика за последние 24 часа:

[image: img10]

Наш способ использования SQL довольно прост, а проще — значит быстрее. И хотя некоторые запросы могут быть довольно заумными, наше взаимодействие с самим SQL особой сложностью не отличается. У нас есть унаследованный [Linq2Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx), но все новые разработки используют [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), нашу библиотеку Micro-ORM с открытым исходным кодом, использующую объекты [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object). Выражусь иначе: в базе данных Stack Overflow есть только одна хранимая процедура и я твердо намерен перенести этот пережиток прошлого в код.

#### Библиотеки

Что ж, давайте сменим тему: теперь о том, что может быть полезно лично *вам*. Выше я уже упоминал о некоторых библиотеках, но завершении я бы хотел привести более обширный список библиотек .Net с открытым исходным кодом, поддерживаемых нами для всех, кто захочет ими воспользоваться. Мы сделали их таковыми, потому что особой бизнес-ценностью они не обладают, но могут помочь программистам всего мира. Надеюсь, вам они пригодятся:

- [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) (.NET Core) — высокопроизводительная библиотека Micro-ORM для ADO.NET.
- [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) — высокопроизводительный клиент Redis.
- [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) — простое приложение протоколирования, используемое нами на каждой странице (с поддержкой Ruby, Go и Node).
- [Exceptional](https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional) — Регистратор ошибок для SQL, JSON, MySQL, и т.п.
- [Jil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil) - высокопроизводительный (де)сериализатор JSON.
- [Sigil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/sigil) — средство генерации .NET CIL кода (когда C# оказывается недостаточно быстрым).
- [NetGain](https://github.com/StackExchange/NetGain) — высокопроизводительный сервер Websocket.
- [Opserver](https://github.com/opserver/Opserver/tree/overhaul) — панель мониторинга, непосредственно проверяющая работоспособность большинства систем, а также принимающая данные Orion, Bosun и WMI.
- [Bosun](http://bosun.org/) — система мониторинга серверов, написанная на Go.
  В следующей публикации будет подробный перечень актуального аппаратного обеспечения, на котором работает наш код. После этого мы пройдемся по пунктам [этого списка](https://trello.com/b/0zgQjktX/blog-post-queue-for-stack-overflow-topics).

Следите за обновлениями!

---

Свободный перевод публикации [@Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) «[Stack Overflow: The Architecture - 2016 Edition](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/)»

Comment: Вот ещё на хабре другой перевод: https://habrahabr.ru/company/ua-hosting/blog/278391/

Comment: Да, видел. Правильную атрибуцию так и не научились на Хабре делать.

Comment: Спасибо за отчет,  и хорошие циски, тоже работаю с такими.