# Склонения и буква Ё в описании к метке пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Как показано на изображении, вместо "раз" нужно "раза", а вместо "Награжден" нужно "Награждён".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на счет ё сомнительно

Comment: @Grundy почему?

Comment: У нас было обсуждение в самом начале переезда, и было решено везде, где правильно с точки зрения правописания, использовать «ё» (а также типографские кавычки и длинное тире, да).

Answer (score 5):

Вообще речь идёт о знаке, а не об участнике. Вот оригинал и текущий перевод, е на ё я уже исправил:

[Tx:2232](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263969?key=c57c9bdcab1db23336ae5ce2f042f34b)

> Awarded $relativeTime$ to
>   Награждён $relativeTime$ для

[Tx:2233](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263969?key=d091724c55f9753876af63441079d93b)

> Awarded $relativeTime$
>   Награждён $relativeTime$

[Tx:2237](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263969?key=f889707e690e5105687fe5eb64fc2964)

> Awarded
>   Награждён
>    Developer note: REFERS TO:badge

Это ж вообще абсурд. В этом слове нужно заменить все буквы. Вот тут уже хороший перевод:

[Tx:2235](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263969?key=e1997e701c3f1236328317092972491e)

> Awarded $__count$ times
>   Присвоен $__count$ раз

Изменил три вышеуказанных строки на "Присвоен". А "для" там вообще не нужно.

Будет исправлено [со следующим обновлением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3139/181472).